# Is application bundle fully replaced on upgrade from App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

The following use case:

1. create a strings file (not localized) and deploy the application to your test device
2. localize the file (en.lproj or similar), make some changes to the new file and remove the original file
3. deploy the application on the device

What I noticed that very often (always?) the application will still use the old non-localized file. The reason is that apparently the file is still in somewhere the application bundle, even though it has been removed from the project. iOS's logic is that if a file of a specific type is looked up, it first checks in the root of the bundle for the non-localized version, and only if it doesn't find it does it go deeper into the localized folders. (Is it just me, or is this logic kind of backwards? I'm used to first looking for language specific file, and then falling back to some defaults, but it might be my Java background.)

Sometimes (always?) removing the app from the device completely doesn't help either. What does in this case is a CMD+SHIFT+K, which cleans the build folder, and after the app is built and deployed again, the correct file is used.

A worse problem would be if such a thing leads to an app crash, like some strange issues with Nibs or whatever - I have seen those as well...

The question is: what would happen if the first version of my app in the apple store had the non-localized file, and the second version localized it? When the user upgrades the app, would they get the same behavior as me during development (i.e. outdated, non-localized file used)?

I can't imagine because I think this would be a cause of a lot of grieving and bug requests, but I can't tell for sure as I haven't yet published any iOS app.

If the behavior is correct when upgrading from the store, why is it? What is so different? Are the files stored locally on my computer somewhere and used when I deploy?

Can anybody share their experiences?